# How to add the icon image into the CheckBoxTreeItem?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I've problem with the TreeView component, It has the CheckBoxTreeItem to check enable or disable, it's very select and unselect with this reference ==> Using JavaFX UI Controls: Tree View | JavaFX 2 Tutorials and Documentation with Using Tree Cell Editors.
This is the image with the tree view have CheckBoxTreeItem 
(http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/img/tree-view-checkbox1.png)

At now, I want to add the icon image beside the CheckBoxTreeItem (Its mean that we have the icon image beside the checkbox).

Could anyone help me this problem?

I saw that when I set like that
tree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.forTreeView());
==> It can not show the icon

This is my coding

```
package sample;  
import javafx.application.Application;  
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;  
import javafx.scene.Node;  
import javafx.scene.Parent;  
import javafx.scene.Scene;  
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBoxTreeItem;  
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;  
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTreeCell;  
import javafx.scene.image.Image;  
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;  
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;  
import javafx.stage.Stage;  
public class Main extends Application {  
    @Override  
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{  
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");  
        Node graphic  = new ImageView(new Image("https://duke.kenai.com/iconSized/duke4.gif"));  
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootItem =  
                new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("View Source Files", graphic);  
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);  
        final TreeView tree = new TreeView(rootItem);  
        tree.setEditable(true);  
        tree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<String>forTreeView());  
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {  
            final CheckBoxTreeItem<String> checkBoxTreeItem =  
                    new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Sample" + (i+1), graphic);  
            rootItem.getChildren().add(checkBoxTreeItem);  
        }  
        tree.setRoot(rootItem);  
        tree.setShowRoot(true);  
        StackPane root = new StackPane();  
        root.getChildren().add(tree);  
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));  
        primaryStage.show();  
    }  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        launch(args);  
    }  
}
```

Thanks 4 your reading.

Tran Quoc Ung

Answer (score 0):

I did it and you should refer in that page ==> https://forums.oracle.com/message/11232268#11232268

Answer (score 0):

CheckBoxTreeItem have a one object property we cannot use more than one object within it.

try this..

```
CheckBoxTreeItem<ImageView> chkbobj;
ImageView mv = new ImageView();
mv.setImage(new Image(getClass().getResourceStreamAs("abc.png")));
chkboobj.setGraphic(mv);
```